# NPM compiles corrupted app.js

Tags: laravel, npm, vuejs2

I am using `Laravel 5.5` preset `vue` and every time I run `npm install && npm run dev` I get app.js with corrupted characters, a full line of *******

Typically this happens at the end of the file app.js

My package.json

```
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.17",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "cross-env": "^5.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "vue": "^2.1.10",
    "vuetify": "1.0.0-alpha.2"
}
```

assets/js/app.js file

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');
window.Vuetify = require('vuetify');

Vue.use(Vuetify);
Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));
Vue.component('example-vuetify', require('./components/ExampleVuetify.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

[image: Chrome Console Error]
The only way I manage to resolve this is by running `rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean && npm install && npm run dev` but then I have to wait forever every time I make any changes to components

Comment: what OS do you use?

Comment: Linux x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Do you have any errors when using your app? And can you post that compiled app.js file

Comment: Edited post with app.js and error image

Comment: check your source files there has to be one with those stars that appears later in compiled app.js

Comment: those stars don't get produced on `npm run production`

Comment: If your code works without any problem then that is OK, it is normal... Only if you get errors while using the app, that is problem. Anyway when the app is deployed you will use npm run production anyway!

Comment: The app breaks when I run `npm run dev` same with `npm run watch`, it only works with production which is not meant for development

Comment: OK, then there is probably something wrong with your source files. Try to compile by excluding them one by one and you will get to the point where you don't get the error and those stars.... and then you will know which file is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no way to solve this at all, the best way I managed to get this fixed is by running:

`rm public/mix-manifest.json && rm public/css/app.css && rm public/js/app.js && npm cache clear --force && npm install && npm run dev`

I hope this helps someone